# Can a for loop be declared like this?

Tags: c++

`for(int i(5) ; i-->0 ; )
{
  //use i as iterator here
}`

Is this the same as

`for(int i=5; i>0 ; i--)` ??

I tried to find similar declarations in google but didn't find anything

Also please suggest cleaner ways to declare the same thing ?

Comment: I'm going to go ahead and say - even if it does work, never ever do this - it would be semantically wrong.

Comment: Yes it is someone else's code. Really ol, I am trying to make it cleaner?  any suggestions for a clean declaration to do the same thing ?

Comment: `for(int i=4; i>=0 ; i--)`

Comment: Yes, a for loop can be declared like that. No, it should never be, because as you've discovered it's much harder to understand than the usual form.

Comment: @MarcGlisse  thanks I will try that implementation

Comment: Marc Glisse, yours works for int signed like here but the construct at the top works for unsigned ints too.

Comment: @CashCow `i+1>0` or `i!=-1` or whatever then.

Answer (score 8):

No these aren't the same.  In the first case, `i` will be decremented before the loop body is executed for the first time.

See http://ideone.com/AbHF3m for a working demo.

Comment: So it is --i instead of i-- ?

Comment: @user1967230: no. That would decrement it before checking the loop condition.

Comment: Can you type an alternate way to declare the first statement ?

Comment: Not true. i-- FIRST evaluates i and then decrements so i-->0 evaluates to 5, then compares 5>0 and then decrements to 4 in the first iteration

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: Yes, but then `i` is 4 when the loop body executes.  Unlike the other version, where it's 5 the first time it executes.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth NO, it's not 5 in the firts iteration in the other version either. TRY THE CODE and see by yourself.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: Follow the link I posted.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: In the other version i gets decrement after the loop body! So you're wrong.

Comment: S0 should I do this for(i=5 ; i>0 ;) { i-- ; rest of the body}

Comment: @user1967230: Do you want to go from 4 to 0 or from 5 to 1? If you want the first go with `for(int i = 4; i>=0; --i) { //...`

Answer (score 4):

It's not the same. In the first case, the value of `i` will be `4` in the first iteration and `0` in the last one. In the second case, `i` will be `5` in the first iteration and `1` in the last one.

**Edit**

For @Y.Ecarri:

First case:

1. Set `i` to `5`
2. Compare `i > 0`, that is, `5 > 0`
3. Decrement `i`. `i` is now `4`
4. Enter body of loop with `i` having value `4`
5. Body finishes

Second case:

1. Set `i` to `5`
2. Compare `i > 0`, that is, `5 > 0`
3. Enter body of loop with `i` having value `5`
4. Body finishes
5. Decrement `i`. `i` is now `4`

Comment: Not true. i-- FIRST evaluates i and then decrements so i-->0 evaluates to 5, then compares 5>0 and then decrements to 4 in the first iteration.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: You keep posting this, but that's exactly why the two versions are different!

Answer (score 4):

No, it's not the same. The first version compares the value of `i` *before* the decrement, and performs the decrement *before* each iteration; the second compares the value *after* the decrement, and performs the decrement *after* each iteration.

So the first iterates over `{4,3,2,1,0}`, while the second iterates over `{5,4,3,2,1}`.

Comment: Not true. i-- FIRST evaluates i and then decrements so i-->0 evaluates to 5, then compares 5>0 and then decrements to 4 in the first iteration.

Comment: @user1967230: The `i>0` in that version has no effect, but otherwise yes; `i--` will give the same boolean result as `i-->0` if `i` starts out non-negative.

Comment: @Y.Ecarri: That's exactly what I said. The first version compares the value of `i` *before* the decrement (i.e. compares `5>0`), and performs the decrement *before* each iteration (i.e. decrements to 4 for the first iteration).

Comment: Ok, you're right. Both loops iterate the same number of times but the variable will have different values.

Answer (score 0):

They are not the same as others have pointed out as order is:

1. first part of the for loop (before first semicolon) is evaluated once only at the start.
2. Second section is evaluated prior to the block of the code, which will not be evaluated at all of the second section returns a zero-value (false, null pointer or 0 numeric). Within this section which parses as i-- > 0, the comparison takes place before the decrement, as it is a post-decrement operator. Thus when i was initially 1 it will be true, but then i will decrement to 0 for what comes next which is
3. The body of the loop.
4. The 3rd part of the for loop is executed at the end of the block of the loop if it is not abnormally terminated (with break or return).

If `i` is a signed int as here so it can reach -1, you can replace with

```
for( int i=4; i >= 0; --i ) { // body
```

which looks a bit more obvious in its intention. If you have an unsigned int e.g. size_t, you can still make it look a bit more obvious in its intent by switching the order

```
for( size_t i = 5; 0 < i--; ) { // body
```

You can also remove the 0 and the comparison altogether and just do

```
for( size_t i = 5; i--; ) { // body
```

In both of the above two I am still uncomfortable with the fact that you start `i=5` when you really want it to start as 4 for the first iteration. So I might even switch to do...while.. Of course I have to initialise `i` outside the loop.

```
size_t i = 5;
do { // body
    --i; // clearly 4 now on first iteration
} while( i != 0 );
```

Comment: i is a unsigned long int, none of the declarations seem clean enough ? thanks though

Comment: Note that the value of `i` is different between the first and the last two examples. I will be decremented before the execution of the loops body while in the first example it gets decremented after the body. Have a look at Mike Seymours answer. Maybe you should highlight this with `//body i =4` in your example.

Comment: sorry edited the first block to use i=4 as the first value, which now gives you the same.